# Layout margin top not working on two xml in Android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, mobile

I've been Having trouble with my layout didn't automatically scroll when typing and selecting input type contact number, I have two `xml` file with this layout one is for the body of my input fields and the other one is the footer which has previous and next button, I tried using `android:layout_marginTop="100dp"` to my footer XML but didn't work, can anyone help me with this

[image]

**body.xml**

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="I. Demographics"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="660dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/til_hh_id"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    app:counterEnabled="true"
                    app:counterMaxLength="30"
                    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                    app:errorEnabled="true"
                    app:helperText="Search Household ID!"
                    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
                    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_hh">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edt_hh_id"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Household no."
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:maxLength="30"
                        android:text="160310001-"

                        />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnSearchHh"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="Search"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/til_set"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/til_search"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    app:helperText="Required"
                    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
                    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_assigned">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/aat_set"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:hint="Set"
                        android:inputType="none" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/til_last_name"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/til_set"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                    app:helperText="Required"
                    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
                    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_person">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edt_last_name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Last Name:"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/til_first_name"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/til_last_name"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                    app:helperText="Required"
                    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
                    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_lastname">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edt_first_name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="First name"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/til_middle_name"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/til_first_name"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_middle">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edt_middle_name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Middle name"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

       
                
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/til_relationship_to_grantee"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/til_middle_name"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    app:helperText="Required"
                    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
                    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_escalator_warning_24">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/aat_relationship_to_grantee"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:hint="Relationship to Grantee" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/til_contact_no"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/til_relationship_to_grantee"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    app:counterEnabled="true"
                    app:counterMaxLength="10"
                    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                    app:helperText="Required"
                    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edt_contact_no"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/icon_contacts"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_contacts"
                        android:drawablePadding="6dp"
                        android:hint="Contact No."
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:maxLength="10" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/til_contact_no_of"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/til_contact_no"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    app:helperText="Required"
                    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
                    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_24">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/aat_contact_no_of"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:hint="Contact No. of?" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

          

            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**footer.xml**

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Scanner.ScanCashCard">


        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/layoutDots"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPrev"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:text="PREV"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:text="NEXT"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id ="@+id/imageIv"
            android:height ="60dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Updated** in my Manifest I added `windowSoftInputMode` but it seems does not work

```
 <activity
   android:name=".Scanner.ScanCashCard"
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"
   android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"/>
```

Comment: Need help , can anyone know this?

Comment: Add the manifest declaration of the activity where this happens.

Comment: @TheLibrarian What do you mean? how can I add manifest of activity?

Comment: In AndroidManifest you have to have defined activity for the screen where this happens(add it to the post). There is an Activity attribute windowSoftInputMode that could potentionally fix the problem.

Comment: @TheLibrarian I tried adding `windowSoftInputMode` please see the updated code above, but the result is the same, need help

Comment: Can anyone knows this? still not found the solution

Comment: Set `android:layout_height="match_parent"` for `<ScrollView>`

Comment: @PawanSinghHarariya Thanks, but is there anyway to automatically scroll up the layout or scroll view when the keyboards shows? I tried `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"` but it seems didn't work for me because I have two combined layout xml

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `<FrameLayout>` as root tag to stack footer layout and body layout on top of each other
2. Use `<include>` tag to add your footer.xml layout into body.xml
3. Set `android:layout_height="match_parent"` for `<ScrollView>`
4. No need of setting this `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"`

**Note:** This will make only the things inside `<ScrollView>` to scroll up rest layout will be constant over screen when softboard appears and I think it makes sense. Ignore icons and color in gif attached.

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/primary"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:text="I. Demographics"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnSearchHh"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="Search"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/til_hh_id"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    app:counterEnabled="true"
                    app:counterMaxLength="30"
                    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                    app:errorEnabled="true"
                    app:helperText="Search Household ID!"
                    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
                    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_hh">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edt_hh_id"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Household no."
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:maxLength="30"
                        android:text="160310001-"

                        />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/til_set"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/til_search"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    app:helperText="Required"
                    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
                    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_assigned">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/aat_set"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:hint="Set"
                        android:inputType="none" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/til_last_name"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/til_set"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                    app:helperText="Required"
                    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
                    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_person">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edt_last_name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Last Name:"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/til_first_name"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/til_last_name"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                    app:helperText="Required"
                    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
                    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_lastname">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edt_first_name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="First name"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/til_middle_name"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/til_first_name"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_middle">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edt_middle_name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Middle name"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/til_relationship_to_grantee"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/til_middle_name"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    app:helperText="Required"
                    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
                    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_escalator_warning_24">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/aat_relationship_to_grantee"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:hint="Relationship to Grantee" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/til_contact_no"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/til_relationship_to_grantee"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    app:counterEnabled="true"
                    app:counterMaxLength="10"
                    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                    app:helperText="Required"
                    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edt_contact_no"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/icon_contacts"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_contacts"
                        android:drawablePadding="6dp"
                        android:hint="Contact No."
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:maxLength="10" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/til_contact_no_of"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/til_contact_no"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    app:helperText="Required"
                    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
                    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_24">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/aat_contact_no_of"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:hint="Contact No. of?" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/footer"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

[image: ScreenPlay]